# Why does FactoryBot keep assigning the same value for lat/lng each time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have the following locations factory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :location do
    valid_points = [
      # a bunch of points in format ["lng", "lat"]
    ]
    point = valid_points.sample
    geography = RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(srid: 4326).point(point[0], point[1])

    street_1 { Faker::Address.street_address }
    street_2 { Faker::Address.secondary_address }
    city { Faker::Address.city }
    state { Faker::Address.state }
    country { Faker::Address.country }
    lonlat { geography }
    longitude { point[0] }
    latitude { point[1] }
  end
end
```

Unfortunately this keeps making locations with the same point that was sampled.  How can I have random point each time a location is created?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [FactoryBot callbacks](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#callbacks)

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :location do    
    street_1 { Faker::Address.street_address }
    street_2 { Faker::Address.secondary_address }
    city { Faker::Address.city }
    state { Faker::Address.state }
    country { Faker::Address.country }

    after(:build) do |location| 
      valid_points = [
        # a bunch of points in format ["lng", "lat"]
      ]
      point = valid_points.sample
      geography = RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(srid: 4326).point(point[0], point[1])

      location.lonlat = geography
      location.latitude = point[1]
      location.longitude = point[0]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: you can move `valid_points` before `factory :location do`. No need to define it every time, rest is fine.